# Parallel computation in R for shell commands

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have use case where i am trying to run call my Rscript over a bunch of files. I have written down the snippet below -

```
for(i in 1:length(fileNames)){

  generateTolerancesCommand = paste(c("Rscript ",modelScriptName,
                                      " --inp=",paste(c("'",dimensionsFolder, "/", fileNames[i],"'"), collapse = ""),
                                      " --sea=",seasonal,
                                      " --freq=",freq,
                                      " --outp=",paste(c("'",outputFolder,"/","'"), collapse=""),
                                      " --tp=",tp,
                                      " --sd=",sd,
                                      " --end=",end,
                                      " --op=",op,
                                      " --tls=",tls,
                                      " --pts=",pts,
                                      " --userf=",paste(c("'",dimensionsFeedbackFolder, "/", fileNames[i],"'"), collapse = "")
                                     ),collapse="")
  system(generateTolerancesCommand)
}
```

This works fine, but it usually takes around 3-4 minutes for 1 loop to finish eventually taking around 2 hours currently to finish the script. I think i can do it better by making it parallel. In each iteration, I am producing an independent snippet of R execution run which can work on an independent data-set. 
I tried reading on parallel libraries like parallel, doParallel in R, but i am not able to figure out the best way which can be applied for my usecase. Can someone experienced in this suggest me a way ?

Comment: Your scripts are returning something? Writing to the global env? What do you want to get out of them?

Comment: Yes, they produce an output in the defined folder passed as command  line argument.

Comment: FYI, instead of adding shell quotes manually, use `shQuote(str)`; it is OS-specific and takes care of escaping of certain characters etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to create variables in the environment but just write some output files, you can just replace your loop with `foreach`.

```
library(foreach)
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores() - 1) 
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
foreach(i = seq_along(fileNames), .combine = 'c') %dopar% {

  ## PUT YOUR CODE HERE

  NULL
}
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

The `NULL` here with the `.combine = 'c'` is just so that `foreach` returns nothing (just a `NULL`), because `foreach` works more than an `lapply` than a for-loop. You can learn more with [this tutorial](https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/).

Comment: I have run my code as suggested by you. Let me evaluate the performance. Is there a way to check how many parallel shell commands are running in parallel. Essentially my code inside the foreach invokes system().

Comment: @PrakharGupta Open your system monitor. You'll one process called `R` for each core used.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can you recommend me some good design patterns implementations in R blog too.

Comment: @PrakharGupta Not sure what you mean by "good design patterns implementations"

Comment: I am a java programmer and I am fairly new to R script. I wanted to know, Is there a good code writing design approach which i could follow.